# Length Required error on apex_web_service.make_rest_request?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm running Oracle 18c and I'm trying to send the following command to a server using apex_web_service.make_rest_request :

```
curl -X POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/XXX/Messages.json \
--data-urlencode "Body=Hi there" \
--data-urlencode "From=+15017122661" \
--data-urlencode "To=+15558675310" \
-u XXX:YYY
```

I tried :

```
apex_web_service.g_request_headers.delete();               
apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).name := 'Content-Type';  
apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).value := 'application/json';            

Output := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(p_url => 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/XXX/Messages.json', 
                                             p_http_method => 'POST', 
                                             p_body => null, 
                                             p_username =>'XXX', 
                                             p_password=>'YYY',
                                             p_parm_name=>apex_util.string_to_table('From:Body:To'),
                                             p_parm_value => apex_util.string_to_table('+15017122661:Hi there:+15558675310'));
```

But I'm getting Length Required error.

I added then to the header :

```
apex_web_service.g_request_headers(2).name := 'Content-Length';
apex_web_service.g_request_headers(2).value := 2000;
```

But when I add this, the request takes so long (around 2 minutes) and fails because of a timeout... I guess my problem is content length value. I don't know what to put exactly here.

Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

Thanks.
Cheers,

Comment: Your body is null, so how can the length be 2000?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
apex_web_service.g_request_headers(2).name := 'Accept';
apex_web_service.g_request_headers(2).value := '*/*';
apex_web_service.g_request_headers(3).name := 'Content-Length';
apex_web_service.g_request_headers(3).value := '0';
```